# CTF - upload a file that runs php scripts

Tags: php, exploit, ctf

I'm participating in a CTF, and I need to upload a file that, once loaded, executes a PHP script—any PHP script. The challenge is that the website only accepts file extensions like `.jpg`, `.png`, `.gif`, and `.bmp`.

The given clue is "unknown extension."

Thanks.

I attempted naming it `php.php.jpg`, which allowed the upload, but unfortunately, the PHP script doesn't run after loading. I also experimented with `exiftool`, but encountered the same issue.

I also tried `file.php%00.jpg`, but it didn't work.

Comment: _The given clue is "unknown extension."_ Is this an indication that we need to try and upload a file that is not  `.jpg, .png, .gif, or .bmp`?

Comment: I think yea. After upload, url doesnt change and when i tried to rename it in burp suite it also failed

Comment: Then upload some random `.gitignore` file and see.

Comment: .gitignore isnt jpg/png/gif/bmp. I got an error

Comment: Where are the non-image files being rejected? If the web page is blocking your upload, perhaps you could try bypassing it and uploading a file directly from the command line.